# Qt widget sizes limits

Tags: qt, layout, size, qwidget

I need to set sizepolicy for QWidget so that the width of the widget is always a multiple of 6 when resizing in the layout (width = 6,12,18,24,30,36...) and height is always a multiple of 4. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to process resize events of your widget. Either subclass the widget and reimplement `resizeEvent` method or install an event filter for the widget. In the resize event handler check current size and correct it when necessary:

```
QSize size = widget->size();
size.setWidth(qRound(size.width() / 6) * 6);
size.setHeight(qRound(size.height() / 4) * 4);
if (size != widget->size()) {
  widget->resize(size);
}
```